# Is it possible to block completely some specific countries using WAF in aws, without having the load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, ubuntu-16.04, magento2, amazon-waf

I have hosted Magento2 site on AWS with an EC2 Instance. **I don't have used any Load Balancer**.

But as per requiremnt, I want to block some countries visitors completely.

I tried using WAF and "Geographic Match Conditions", but during configuration it is asking to set the "AWS Resource" , which only have options for "Application load balancer" and "REST API". But I donot have any load balancer.

**So is it possible to block some specific countries(completely) with help of WAF section in AWS, without having any load balancer?**

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage CloudFront and its *geo restriction* feature. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/georestrictions.html

If you want to be even more flexible on restriction rules to apply, integrate CloudFront and WAF.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-awswaf.html

WBR

Comment: Maksim Aniskov, Thankyou for your reply. will this block visitors completely accesing the website Or only cloufront resources will be blocked ?

Comment: You would need to configure your entire site to use CloudFront, and then configure your server to only accept requests that came *though* CloudFront.